# Change URI using Java Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get the id of selected option from dropdown. I have tried like this:

```
<a id="edit_link" href=""><button>Edit</button> </a>
```

Then in javascript i do like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#base_ini_id').change(function() { 
            var id = $("#base_ini_id").val();   
            $("#edit_link").attr("href","/customer/upload_ini/edit_ini_old/"+id); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

My Current URL is this:

```
/customer/user/edit/1
```

Now on this page I have another edit button which point to this:

```
/customer/upload_ini/edit_ini_old/1
```

But when I click on that button it goes to this:

```
/customer/user/edit/1
```

Why is this? Below is my code:

```
<tr>
    <?php 
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) 
        { 
            $id = $_GET['id']; 
            btn_edit($id); 
        } 
    ?>  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <td> 
        <select required name="base_ini_id" id="base_ini_id" class="form-control"> 
            <option value="">Select</option> 
            <?php foreach($base as $value) { ?> 
                <option id="emp" class="specialLink" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>">
                    <?php echo $value->base_ini_filename;?>
                </option> 
            <?php } ?> 
        </select> 
    </td> 
    <td> 
        <a id="edit_link" href="/customer/upload_ini/edit_ini_old/">
            <button>Edit</button>
        </a> 
    </td> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#base_ini_id').change(function() { 
                var id = $("#base_ini_id").val();   
                $("#edit_link").attr("href","/customer/upload_ini/edit_ini_old/" + id); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
</tr>
```

Comment: could you put your code on JSFiddle to test

Comment: Not related, but there's something wrong there : `foreach($base as $value) { ?>  <option id="emp" ...`. IDs should be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: @claspina this might help https://jsfiddle.net/sohp7ofd/

Comment: here what i am trying to do is to get the id of selected option and want to pass that id to edit method

Comment: @Rajan your code on JSFiddle doesn't work to test. What is exactly your problem?

Comment: As mentioned my javascript changes my uri, see i am on a page with uri :/customer/user/edit/1 and i have a edit button which points to this uri:  /customer/upload_ini/edit_ini_old/1 but when i click on the button it remains the same page

Comment: @Rajan When you change the selected option and then place your mouse over the Edit button, you should see a URL appear at the bottom of your browser. Is it the right one?

Comment: yes the url is correct @blex

Comment: @blex its uri i want to go on but when i click on button it goes to current page why so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer using this script:

```
<tr>
<td>Base INI File</td>
  <?php 

if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
{ 
$id=$_GET['id']; 
btn_edit_file($id); 
} 
?>  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 


<td> 
<select required name="base_ini_id" id="base_ini_id" class="form-control"> 

<option value="">Select</option> 
<?php foreach($base as $value) 
{ 
  ?> 

<option id="emp" class="specialLink" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>" 
  <?php if($value->id == $user->base_ini_id){echo "selected";} ?>>
  <?php echo $value->base_ini_filename;?></option>

<?php } ?> 

</select> 
</td> 

<td> 
<?php echo btn_edit('customer/upload_ini/edit_ini_custom/'); ?> 
</td> 


<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#base_ini_id').change(function() { 
                var id = $("#base_ini_id").val();
                var url = "/bizrtc/customer/upload_ini/edit_ini_custom/";

                $("#edit_link").attr("href",url+ id); 
                $("#edit_link").attr("target","_blank");

            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
 </tr>
```